# Getting NullPointerException, while trying to get deviceID

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the deviceID, to work with AdMob on my device (yes, I know that I can show it in LogCat, but it is just a basic program, I thought I can write without problem), but I get NullPointerException for some reason. I have added the deviceid textview in the layout, so I don't exactly understand what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final TextView deviceId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
    deviceId.setText(deviceid);
}

 //These are just autogenerated  by SDK, so don't think they are matter.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
    }

}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.deviceid.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Device ID:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:id="@+id/device"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I saw correctly in LogCat there is a problem with this line:

```
deviceId.setText(deviceid);
```

How can I solve it?

EDIT1: Here is my logcat:

```
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deviceid/com.example.deviceid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at com.example.deviceid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-20 11:32:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

Comment: is that layout fragment_main.xml?

Comment: Please check my previous post. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19226843/1129468)

Comment: Did you take permission from manifest..

Comment: getDeviceId could return null as said here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId() . So you should handle this.

Comment: @Zoubiock there is no need. If you call setText(null) it clears the content of the TextView.

Comment: looks like the textviews belong to fragment

Comment: @blackbelt yes it is the layout fragment_main.xml

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya yes I have added READ_PHONE STATE permission

Comment: Hooo ! you're right. In the onCreated method fragment is not attached yet. So the view doesn't exist at that time

Answer (score 2):

Since your TextView belongs to  `fragment_main.xml` , you can change the onCreateView method this way:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        final TextView deviceId = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.device);
        final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (tm != null) {
           String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
           deviceId.setText(deviceid);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should change the onCreate method to this?

Comment: yes I do, because your textview belongs to the Fragment view hierarchy at that time

Comment: I understand and sorry I came from the "old" Android times with a big pause in development and I'm not exactly on the top now... :) Now I don't get any error, but my emulator writes only 000000000000000 where it should write the deviceid. Is it because it is an emulator or something went wrong again?

Comment: It is because of the emulator. Also you should check for devices without TelephonyManager

Comment: Thanks, but I just would like to use it on my own device with 4.0 so as far as I know it should have this option (I hope that I'm right). I will try it on my device. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't give me any numbers on a real device. Don't know why, but it just show me blank place where it should show the device id. What can be the problem?

Comment: maybe the String returned is null. Can you try to add some log?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` belongs to the fragment. So you need to initialize as below

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 TextView deviceId = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.device);
 TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
 deviceId.setText(deviceid);
 return rootView;
```

Or in `onActivityCreated`

```
 TextView deviceId = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.device);
```