# Use Purchase Status API to validate NON InApp Purchase

Tags: android, authentication, in-app-purchase, google-play

According to this topic: [Can I use Purchase Status API to validate if app was bought via Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165994/can-i-use-purchase-status-api-to-validate-if-app-was-bought-via-play-store) the Google Play Developer API provides a Purchase Token which can be fetched any time. So I imagine to send this purchase token to my backend server to ensure this user has already paid for my app, like it is written here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#practices

Since the first comment on the posted anwer (see above first link) is, that there is no way to check if the playstore confirms the purchase I am confused.

I dont want to use InApp Purchases. I want my users to be able to buy an app and receive a piece of information for validating this google user has purchased it - in order to store set a flag in my own backend: "UserA: has_paid = true"

How can I achieve this?