# Way to detect if the user has really downloaded my app from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to prevent an app from being executed by those users who have received it not through buying from google market? By 'way', I mean any 'approach' you can think of.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865162/how-to-secure-my-app-against-piracy

Answer (score 1):

In case you're developing a paid app, you can use the available [Purchase Status API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html) for verifying the user's purchase status.