# How google protect paid application apk?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am new to the Android publishing. I created a regular tool app.

I wonder, anyone can buy my app and export apk. Is this apk file protected. Can anyone use it ?

Thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure my app against piracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865162/how-to-secure-my-app-against-piracy)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267981/should-i-spend-time-preventing-piracy-of-my-app